# Django Rest Framework CreateAPIView url primary key should be come from another model, not respected model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

At first see my models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import  User
class Group(models.Model):
    person = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        through='PersonGroup',
        related_name='person_of_the_group'
    )


class PersonGroup(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(
        Group,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='group_person_of_group'
    )
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        User, 
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
```

and this is my views:

```
class AddGroupMembers(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = PersonGroupSerializers
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    lookup_field = 'pk'

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Make requst data mutable
        if not request.data._mutable:
            request.data._mutable = True

        request.data['person'] = request.user.pk
        request.data['group'] = kwargs['pk']
        serializer = PersonGrouperializers(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

and this is my serializes:

```
class PersonGroupSerializers(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = PersonGroup
        fields = '__all__
```

I want the urls pk will be mess pk,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mess/api/v1/mess/<int:mess.pk>/
```

I want when i hit the endpoint, i should able to create `PersonGroup` where, if you see my views, you will know how i am populating this table.

I mean, the endpoint url will be identified by any of `Group` `pk` but there i should able to `PersonGroup`

Hope you got it, can anyone tell me how to achive this?

Comment: `pk` exists only after the objects was created (saved) in the database.

Comment: I know but this is not a case